# i'm trying to work with sqlite, having prob regarding this tutorial

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow a tutorial, here it's link: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

All is going ok, but I just want to know where to place this code:

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

try {
    myDbHelper.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
} try {
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place it in your activity somewhere, but I really don't like that tutorial. You don't want to create a database multiple times so you're going to have to check if it is created already. It's extending SQLiteOpenHelper but with an empty implementation for the actual useful parts.

If you're doing an actual extension of SQLiteOpenHelper - all you have to do is the first line (`DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);`) in your activities `onCreate()`.
Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) out.

Comment: ok let me make it clear, i've created a database, with .sqlite extension, to use it in my project,

i'm confused in its usage... i mean the process of accessing the DB and then retrieving the values from it into my project like in spinners or grid view.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that SQLiteOpenHelper handles mostly everything for you. All you need is to implement onCreate (to create the DB) - and then calling getWritableDatabase() gives you a database object that you can query for retrieving data.

Comment: @Qaiser I agree w/ @ Pescis that tutorial is pretty sloppy. (*ugh* the internet :)  just open and close the thing one time.